# CSS span Positioning issue

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, css-position

### Postioning span in CSS

I'm creating an example rails site but I'm having trouble on index.html.erb: This is the block of my HTML code(this is an example website so names and stuff are made up, i.e FleetFile is not the name of a real service):

```
</center>
<span class="socialnet">

Aol
Google+<br>
MySpace<br>
Orkut<br>
Twitter<br>
Facebook<br>
</span>
</aside>
<span class="servsmadebyus">
Free Web Hosting<br>
Cloud Storage<br>
Paid Web Hosting<br>
FleetFile Free FTP Client<br>
FleetFile Premium<br>
</span>
```

And my CSS:

```
.socialnet {
text-align: left;
color: #000000;
background-color: red; }

.servsmadebyus {
text-align: right;
color: red;
background-color:blue;
}
```

As you can see, i want to position my .servsmadebyus span on the right side but that span is staying on the left side. Even when i put text-align:right;, it stays on left side

Comment: Please remove '<center>' tags from your HTML markup. that's too old-fashioned (199X). You're also mixing hex-color notation and named colors in your CSS code, for sanity better stay with one kind of notation.

Comment: how did that center tag get there? must have been place there from another HTML file that i had saved on accident. also i used the hex codes because i wanted a lighter/darker shade so i had to use the HTML hex color value and i used named color code because the regular shade was just fine, but thanks for the feedback, i apprieciated it.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` should be applied in the parent (block) element, not in the span itself.
You will most probably need to wrap those spans in `block` elements and then `float` them.

Something like the following code:

html:

```
<div class="social">
    <span class="socialnet">
    Aol
    Google+<br>
    MySpace<br>
    Orkut<br>
    Twitter<br>
    Facebook<br>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="serv">
    <span class="servsmadebyus">
    Free Web Hosting<br>
    Cloud Storage<br>
    Paid Web Hosting<br>
    FleetFile Free FTP Client<br>
    FleetFile Premium<br>
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.socialnet {
color: #000000;
background-color: red; }

.servsmadebyus {
color: red;
background-color:blue;
}

.social{
    float: left;
}

.serv{
    float: right;
}

/* below is the clearfix hack, read more here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ */
#wrap:before,
#wrap:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

#wrap:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/KfDK2/